# How do I check values in WiX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.6

I've got the following in WiX:

A dialog offers two checkboxes to install software for Excel 2007 and / or Excel 2010.

```
<Control Type="CheckBox" Id="Excel2007" Width="88" Height="17" X="22" Y="120" Text="Excel 2007" Property="INSTALLEXCEL2007_2010" CheckBoxValue="1" />

<Control Type="CheckBox" Id="Excel2010" Width="88" Height="17" X="22" Y="120" Text="Excel 2010" Property="INSTALLEXCEL2010" CheckBoxValue="1" />
```

I want to evaluate which checkbox has been set by the user to check if the PIAs (tools for Excel 2007 / 2010) have been installed. If not, the installation should be stoppend with a message.

The current problem is:

I can't check for those two values as a launch condition, because I don't know the user's decision. I thought that I might use a condition in the dialog where the checkboxes are, like this:

```
<Publish Dialog="ExcelConfigDlg" Control="ExcelConfigDlg_Proceed" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg"><![CDATA[INSTALLEXCEL2007>="1"]]></Publish>
```

However, this doesn't work. When clicking on the button, the installation routine proceeds.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You have a spelling mistake: `<![CDATA[INSTALLEXCEL2007>="1"]]>` should be `<![CDATA[INSTALLEXCEL2007="1"]]>` also is the property not `INSTALLEXCEL2007_2010`

Comment: @NatalieCarr:
Thanks, that worked. Do you know if it`s possible to raise a message box or cancel installation if the checkbox does not have the value "1"? Do you have to use a custom action to achieve this?

Comment: `<![CDATA[INSTALLEXCEL2007 <> "1"]]>` Will work..:) just publish either a dialog displaying your message or the end dialog with that condition.

Comment: @NatalieCarr: 
Well, you`re right. Shame on me I didn`t use the <>-operator.
But it didn`t raise a message box or else. 
Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to validate a checkbox value and, depending on that, check some more values (received via RegistrySearch). Up to now, I ended up with the following (which is working so far):

```
<Publish Dialog="ExcelChooserDlg" Control="ExcelChooser_Weiter" Event="NewDialog" Value="FileConfigDlg" Order="1"><![CDATA[INSTALLEXCEL2003="1" OR INSTALLEXCEL2007="1" OR INSTALLEXCEL2010="1"]]></Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="ExcelChooserDlg" Control="ExcelChooser_Weiter" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg" Order="2"><![CDATA[INSTALLEXCEL2003<>"1" AND INSTALLEXCEL2007<>"1" AND INSTALLEXCEL2010<>"1"]]></Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="ExcelChooserDlg" Control="ExcelChooser_Weiter" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg" Order="3"><![CDATA[INSTALLEXCEL2007="1" AND OFFICERUNTIME<"10.0.31007"]]></Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="ExcelChooserDlg" Control="ExcelChooser_Weiter" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg" Order="4"><![CDATA[INSTALLEXCEL2007="1" AND OFFICERUNTIME<"10.0.31007" AND OFFICE_2007_PIA<>"Microsoft Office 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies"]]></Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="ExcelChooserDlg" Control="ExcelChooser_Weiter" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg" Order="5"><![CDATA[INSTALLEXCEL2010="1" AND OFFICERUNTIME<"10.0.31007" AND OFFICE_2010_PIA<>"Microsoft Office 2010 Primary Interop Assemblies"]]></Publish>
```

I`m not sure if this is best best solution, but as I stated, it´s working for me so far.

Comment: Just to let you know as well, wen publishing new dialogs, the ordering can be hard to get your head around (was for me) that say you have two conditions that are true, the dialog with the highest order number will get executed.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your first and second question:

```
<Publish Dialog="ExcelConfigDlg" Control="ExcelConfigDlg_Proceed" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg"><![CDATA[INSTALLEXCEL2007_2010="1"]]></Publish>
```

I think you want to raise say a warning dialog if they user does not select any of the check boxes. This is an example of one of my warning dialogs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Fragment>
 <UI>
  <Dialog Id="WarningDlg" Width="260" Height="85" Title="!(loc.Title)">
    <Control Id="Ok" Type="PushButton" X="112" Y="57" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Cancel="yes" Text="Ok">
      <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="Text" Type="Text" X="48" Y="15" Width="194" Height="30" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.IntegerOnlyDlgDecription)" />
    <Control Id="Icon" Type="Icon" X="15" Y="15" Width="24" Height="24" FixedSize="yes" IconSize="32" Text="Exclamation" />
  </Dialog>
</UI>
</Fragment>
```

and use the following:

```
<Publish Dialog="ExcelConfigDlg" Control="ExcelConfigDlg_Proceed" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="WarningDlg"><![CDATA[(INSTALLEXCEL2007_2010<>"1") AND (INSTALLEXCEL2010<>"1")]]></Publish>
```

Comment: No, not quite. I wanted to check some more values in case the checkbox has been set. However, I didn`t write it in my post. Please see my answer below.

Thank you for giving me a huge push in the right direction :-).